# how to join multiple table in java using eclips

Tags: java

if i write code like this

```
PreparedStatement pre1=cn.prepareStatement("insert into Registration(Name,ContactNo,LID)values(?,?,'select LID from Login Where Email="+email+" and Password="+pass+"'");
```

its give an error Like
Incorrect syntax near 'select LID from Login Where Email="" and Password=1233456'.

please help me to remove this error

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a [subquery](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26856). And you can bind the email and password too. Also, you should `close` your `Statement`(s). Something like,

```
String sql = "insert into Registration(Name,ContactNo,LID) values "
        + "(?,?,(select LID from Login Where Email=? and Password=?))";
PreparedStatement pre1 = null;
try {
    pre1 = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
    // ...
    pre1.setString(3, email);
    pre1.setString(4, pass);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (pre1 != null) {
        try {
            pre1.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming one thing that will probably help is to enclose the 'select LID...and Password="+pass+"' with a parenthesis to indicate that this the return value of this section is the third variable to the values function call.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and it works perfectly well on my system,

```
String query = "insert into test.Registration (Name,ContactNo,LID) values(?,?,(select LID from test.Login where Email='"+email+"' and Password1='"+password+"'))";
PreparedStatement p =con.prepareStatement(query);
```

You don't need single quotes around subquery instead enclose it within round parenthesis.